# PHP export image as the same type (PNG, JPG, etc) when using imagecreatefromstring()

Tags: php, image, gd

I have a PHP function which takes arbitrary string and creates image resource from it, autodetecting image format, as follows:

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($image_data_string);
```

As you surely know, this creates the $im image resource when the `$image_data_string` contains any supported image type, like JPG, PNG, etc.

After some manipulation to the $im resource (modifying some pixels etc), I would like to return back the image string again in the same format. That is, if the data string contained PNG image, I want to return string of generated PNG image. If it was JPG then I would like to return it as JPG in string.

PHP supports `imagejpeg()` or `imagepng()` and other functions, so if I knew how to detect the image type of $im resource then I would be all set. There are function like `imagesx()` and `imagesy()` which return width and height of the `$im` resource, but I am unable to find appropriate function which would return the IMAGE TYPE of the `$im` resource.

The only way which comes to my mind is to analyze the first bytes of the original `$image_data_string` in order to find out the image type. But I would prefer a native PHP function for that purpose, which would work on the $im resource argument. Is there anything like that?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you use extra variable to hold the image extension ?

Comment: How are you getting the $image_data_string variable? Is it possible you could also store the filetype at this stage too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code instead

```
$imgdata = base64_decode($image_data_string);

$f = finfo_open();

$mime_type = finfo_buffer($f, $imgdata, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($image_data_string);

$filename = 'somerandomname';

switch($mime_type){
    case 'image/png':

        imagepng($image, $filename.'.png');

    break;
    default:

    break;
}
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: `$image_data_string` is not base64 encoded so I see no reason to decode it. Other than that, thanks for pointing to finfo_open(), that answers the question.